# Determine if Azure is blocking URL

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, ssl

I am trying to configure my .Net 6.0 app for OIDC.  I found that Hybrid and Implicit Flow work fine, but code flow does not.  After further investigation, I see that the issue is that my app (hosted on Azure ASE) cannot reach the .well-known/openid-configuration or jwks_uri pages to complete the authentication.  I can go to these pages directly in my computer browser, but when my OIDC code tries to hit those endpoints I get an error stating:

> "The SSL connection could not be established.  see inner exception.
> Unable to read the data from the transport connection:  a connection
> attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
> after a period of time, or stablished connection failed because the
> connected host failed to respond ..."

I then just setup a small function to test this, which just uses an HttpClient to call the URL and it also gets the same error. Since I can access these files directly, in my browser, is it an Azure issue?  How can I definitely know for sure that Azure is blocking this URL (or if it is my code)?  Here is a sample test code I used:

```
private async Task TestFile(string url){
   try{
      var client = new HttpClient();
      var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
      //log result.StatusCode
  }catch(Exception ex){
    //Log Exception
  }
}
```

I've also  tried to ignore server cert errors like  this:

```
private async Task TestFile(string url){
   var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
  try{
      handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertifacteOption.Manual;
      handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors)=>{
        return true;
      }
      var client = new HttpClient(handler);
      var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
      //log result.StatusCode
  }catch(Exception ex){
    //Log Exception
  }
}
```